# Jquery index() method to get index of child

Tags: jquery, indexing, parent-child

I am using query index() method to get the index of an element relative to its parent.

Here are two codes :
Code1

```
<div id="check1">
    <p>  
        <span> 
            <b> Bold Line 1 </b>
            <b> This is line2 </b>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p> Should have index 1 </p>
</div>
```

Code2

```
<div id="check2">
    <p>  
        <span> 
            <b> Bold Line 1 </b>
            **<p> This is line2 </p>**   //replaced <b> with <p>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p> Should have index 1 </p>
</div>
```

In code2, I just replaced the 2nd bold name with p tag name.

Area of doubt is answer varies in both these cases.
Answers are:

```
Case1: index comes 1
Case2: index comes 3
```

Please check this out. "Click on Should have index 1"
 http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/U73VV/

And moreover, when I click on "This is line2" on both checks, their parents are coming different. In check1, parent is span and in check2 parent is div.

Please let me know what difference I am making just by changing the tagName. Their relative position w.r.t their parent is still same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place `<p/>` tags inside `<p/>` tags. You are ending up with the following markup:

```
<div id="check2">
  <p>  
    <span> 
      <b> Bold Line 1 </b>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p> This is line2 </p>
  <p> Should have index 1 </p>
</div>
```

You might want to replace `<b/>` with a `<span/>` instead to keep the layout.

Or, if what you want is to change the `bold` attribute of the tags, you can use CSS for it. This won't need you to mess around with the layout.

```
.bold { text-weight: bold; }
```

Toggling the `bold` class:

```
<div id="check1">
  <p>  
    <span> 
      <!-- This is bold -->
      <span class="bold"> Bold Line 1 </span>
      <!-- This one is not bold -->
      <span> This is line2 </span>
    </span>
</p>
<p> Should have index 1 </p>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct the answer varies because of invalid markup. I also guessed that but was not sure. Thanks for confirming it. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the ivalid markup. Your'e using nested `<p>`-tags wich isn't allowed. Changing case 2 to this, makes it work.

```
<div id="check2">
    <div>  
        <span> 
            <b> Bold Line 1 </b>
            **<p> This is line2 </p>**   //replaced <b> with <p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <p> Should have index 1 </p>
</div>
```

I don't know why it changes the index, but I do know that the markup is invalid.